# Javascript Encode URL of HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I need to send HTML code that is generated by summer note to my server , my server receives the data through python and my code below seems to work fine , however when i need to encode and send more complex HTML i get a 404 error , any help on what in the below HTML could be causing an issue during encoding?.

below is the html i am encoding:

```
<table class="MsoTableGrid" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border: none;">
 <tbody><tr>
  <td width="354" valign="top" style="width:269.75pt;border:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
  normal"><!--[if gte vml 1]><v:shapetype id="_x0000_t75"
   coordsize="21600,21600" o:spt="75" o:preferrelative="t" path="m@4@5l@4@11@9@11@9@5xe"
   filled="f" stroked="f">
   <v:stroke joinstyle="miter"></v:stroke>
   <v:formulas>
    <v:f eqn="if lineDrawn pixelLineWidth 0"></v:f>
    <v:f eqn="sum @0 1 0"></v:f>
    <v:f eqn="sum 0 0 @1"></v:f>
    <v:f eqn="prod @2 1 2"></v:f>
    <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelWidth"></v:f>
    <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelHeight"></v:f>
    <v:f eqn="sum @0 0 1"></v:f>
    <v:f eqn="prod @6 1 2"></v:f>
    <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelWidth"></v:f>
    <v:f eqn="sum @8 21600 0"></v:f>
    <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelHeight"></v:f>
    <v:f eqn="sum @10 21600 0"></v:f>
   </v:formulas>
   <v:path o:extrusionok="f" gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect"></v:path>
   <o:lock v:ext="edit" aspectratio="t"></o:lock>
  </v:shapetype><v:shape id="Picture_x0020_1" o:spid="_x0000_i1025" type="#_x0000_t75"
   alt="Vantage_spot" style='width:138.75pt;height:54.75pt;visibility:visible;
   mso-wrap-style:square'>
   <v:imagedata src="file:///C:/Users/tws/AppData/Local/Temp/msohtmlclip1/01/clip_image001.wmz"
    o:title="Vantage_spot"></v:imagedata>
  </v:shape><![endif]--><!--[if !vml]--><img width="185" height="73" src="file:///C:/Users/tws/AppData/Local/Temp/msohtmlclip1/01/clip_image002.png" alt="Vantage_spot" v:shapes="Picture_x0020_1"><!--[endif]--><o:p></o:p></p>
  </td>
  <td width="354" valign="top" style="width:269.75pt;border:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt">
  <p class="MsoNormal" align="right" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:right;line-height:normal"><span style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:
  &quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Avanteos Investments Limited<o:p></o:p></span></p>
  <p class="MsoNormal" align="right" style="margin-top:.5pt;margin-right:0in;
  margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-align:right;
  line-height:normal"><span style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Trustee
  ABN 20 096 259 979<o:p></o:p></span></p>
  <p class="MsoNormal" align="right" style="margin-top:.5pt;margin-right:0in;
  margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-align:right;
  line-height:normal"><span style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Fund
  ABN 38 876 896 681<o:p></o:p></span></p>
  <p class="MsoNormal" align="right" style="margin-top:.4pt;margin-right:0in;
  margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-align:right;
  line-height:normal"><span style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">AFSL
  245531<o:p></o:p></span></p>
  <p class="MsoNormal" align="right" style="margin-top:.8pt;margin-right:0in;
  margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-align:right;
  line-height:normal"><span style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
  <p class="MsoNormal" align="right" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:right;line-height:normal"><span style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:
  &quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Locked Bag 3460<o:p></o:p></span></p>
  <p class="MsoNormal" align="right" style="margin-top:.3pt;margin-right:0in;
  margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-align:right;
  line-height:normal"><span style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">GPO
  <st1:place w:st="on"><st1:city w:st="on">MELBOURNE</st1:city></st1:place> VIC
  3001<o:p></o:p></span></p>
  <p class="MsoNormal" align="right" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:right;line-height:normal"><span style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:
  &quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
  <p class="MsoNormal" align="right" style="margin-top:.7pt;margin-right:0in;
  margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-align:right;
  line-height:normal"><span style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Telephone
  1800 701 682<o:p></o:p></span></p>
  <p class="MsoNormal" align="right" style="margin-top:.7pt;margin-right:0in;
  margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-align:right;
  line-height:normal"><span style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Facsimile
  03 9804 0398<o:p></o:p></span></p>
  <p class="MsoNormal" align="right" style="margin-top:.2pt;margin-right:0in;
  margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-align:right;
  line-height:normal"><span style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">vps@colonialfirststate.com.au<o:p></o:p></span></p>
  <p class="MsoNormal" align="right" style="margin-top:.4pt;margin-right:0in;
  margin-bottom:0in;margin-left:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-align:right;
  line-height:normal"><span style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">vantageportfoliosolutions.com.au<o:p></o:p></span></p>
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
  normal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="708" colspan="2" valign="top" style="width:539.5pt;border:none;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
  normal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="708" colspan="2" valign="top" style="width:539.5pt;border:none;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
  normal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

below is the javascript which encodes the html above and sends it to my server via a get request:

```
// this function uploads our new template to the server

function UploadTemplate() {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        var CustomerName = encodeURIComponent($('#CustomerName').val()) // this is the name of the template
        var content = $('#AddTemplate').summernote('code') // this extracts the html from summernote 
        var contentencoded = encodeURIfix(content) // this uri encodes componnet as well as exclamation marks 
        

        // this request uploads the new template and it's content to the database
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://autobots.avanteos.com.au/py/LetterProducer_CustomerDB.py?CustomerName=' + CustomerName.trim() + '&Template=' + contentencoded.trim(), false)
        xhr.send();


        // resolves promise

        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            resolve('success')
        }
    })



}
// this is used to remove exclamation marks for our url encode 
function encodeURIfix(str) {
    return (encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/!/g, '%21')).replace(/'/g, "%27");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is `encodeURIComponent()`

```js
function urlEncodeFunc(x) {
  x = (x + '').toString();

  return encodeURIComponent(x)
    .replace('!', '%21')
    .replace('\'', '%27')
    .replace('(', '%28')
    .replace(')', '%29')
    .replace('*', '%2A')
    .replace('%20', '+');
}

let url = "http://youtube.com/gmkhussain?v=1.4";

console.log( urlEncodeFunc(url) );
```